# How to create custom uiview with custom subview with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to create a custom uiview with dynamic height subviews.
I have created the subview with custom xib.
I am having difficulty finding a way to react uibutton touched and laying out subviews according to the sizes.

Comment: Can you post some code that you did?

Comment: it is a bit of a problem the project im on is private. but i can describe what i did. i basiclly  created custom xib views for and item which is like a cell and a xib for a view that contains those cell. i need a good way to change the height how the container and redraw the views when cells are deleted or added. the problem is the i have a main view which have dynamic amount of container and each container has dynamic amount of cells.

Comment: If it's private, you can add some example code, not necessarily your code. You can change variable and function or something like that.